# Comparator for list on a specific item's field

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

I have a List element.

Every OrderType item has an integer field, priority, that set the priority (1, 2 or 3) of the reassortment of the list.

I want create a comparator that reassort the list from priority 1 to 3. Can I use the *Collections.sort* method?

I saw this example:

```
package com.javacodegeeks.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class SimpleSortExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List list = new ArrayList();

        for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
            list.add((int) (Math.random() * 100));
        }

        System.out.println("Initial List: "+list);
        Collections.sort(list);
        System.out.println("Sorted List: "+list);

    }

}
```

There are some examples [here](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/list/java-sorted-list-example/).

How can I do this?

I tried with:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Integer i1, Integer i2) {
            return (i2.intValue() > i1.intValue()) ? 1 : -1;
        }

    });
```

but I obtain an error, I have to implement the not ovveride method *compare(object, Object)*...

Like *compare(Integer, Integer)* is not an override method.

Comment: Did you  try the second example ?

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand how can I use this only on the integer field priority.... any help on answer?

Comment: use List<Integer> list instead of List list

Comment: I don't want extract the integer fields! I want compare the OrderType items  on the priority

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either you have to use the proper `List<>` type such as `List<Integer>`, then using `Integer` should be fine. This is the adviseable alternative.

Or, if you insist on using the untyped `List`, you should do

```
    @Override
    public int compare(Object i1, Object i2) {
        ...
    }
```

instead. This second alternative is inferior to the other: you have less type safety and have to cast around for being able to use it.

---

For using a `List<OrderType>`, you have to completely change your code, as you cannot do

```
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
        list.add((int) (Math.random() * 100));
    }
```

any longer (of course).

Additionally, the Comparator should be used like

```
    Collections.sort(l, new Comparator<OrderType>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(OrderType o1, OrderType o2) {
            return Integer.compare(oT1.getPriority(), oT2.getPriority());
        }
    });
```

Note especially

- the `Comparator<OrderType>` part which makes `compare()` have the proper parameter types
- the `Integer.compare()` call which makes the check much easier (the other examples fail to compare for equality...)

Comment: I want use a List<OrderType> but order on the priority integer field

Comment: Great! Really this i want! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
public class OrderTypeModel implements Comparable<OrderTypeModel> {

private Integer priority;
    @Override
    public int compareTo(OrderTypeModel o) {

        return priority.compareTo(o.priority);
    }
}
```

You can simply implement Comparable and call Collections.sort on your OrderTypeModel arrayList.

Answer (score 2):

Use the second example from what you gave us

```
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator() {

        @Override
        public int compare(OrderType oT1, OrderType oT2) {
            return (oT1.getPriority() > oT2.getPriority()) ? 1 : -1;
        }

    });
```

You give a comparator and just implement the compare method. This method takes two object of the (List< T >) T parameter. Then you can access a property from each object and compare them.

Consider setting the Generic type of your list of objects.

Comment: ... or just, if Java 8 is used, the much better readable `Collections.sort(list, (OrderType oT1, OrderType oT2) -> (oT1.getPriority() > oT2.getPriority()) ? 1 : -1);`

Comment: ... Which is named lambda expression. Thks glglgl for completing this with more recent features.

Comment: No I don't use Java 8. I have the 7 version.

Comment: If I use the @RPresle solution I obtain this error: The type new Comparator(){} must implement the inherited abstract method Comparator.compare(Object, Object). The method compare(OrderTypeModel, OrderTypeModel) of type new Comparator(){} must override or implement a supertype method

Comment: As I said in the answer consider set the type of your list. `List< OrderTypeModel > = new ArrayList< >()`